# Set default scope of solution explorer in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I have a project that has a lot of dependencies, packages, pre-existing source build files etc that I don't need to quickly access at a glance, if at all, after initial setup.
As such I find myself repeatedly using "scope to this" for my own source files every time I open the project as the rest of the folder structure and files aren't relevant to daily development.

Is there a way to default the explorer to this scope so it is already ready to go on open?

I have yet to find any settings or topics that addresses this specifically when searching.